# Can "a couple of misprints/errors/typos etc." be conveyed by "un couple de coquilles/erreurs/fautes de frappe etc"

Tags: traduction, anglais, usage, faux-amis

L'autre jour j'ai dit:

> Il a fait un couple de fautes.

Un collègue francophone natif m'a corrigé en m'expliquant que la tournure est du type calque anglais et j'aurais dû dire:

> Il a fait quelques fautes.

mais je me rappelle avoir vu quelques exemples de cet emploi [https://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/a+couple+of+mistakes.html].

1. Est-il vrai qu'on ne peut pas employer 'un couple de' dans ce contexte ?
2. Si cela est vrai, pourquoi la différence entre anglais ('a couple of') et français ?
3. Si cela est vrai, quelle tournure rend mieux en français

> He made a couple of mistakes.

> Il a fait quelques fautes/des fautes/deux ou trois fautes...

Quelque chose d'autre ?

Comment: "Si cela est vrai, pourquoi la différence entre anglais ('a couple of') et français ?" Impossible de répondre. Ce ne sont pas les même langues. On dit que c'est un faux ami.

Comment: @Lambie. Merci. Je crois qu'on dit que ce sont des faux amis (ou bien faux-amis).

Comment: On peut dire que **la traduction (singulier)** de couple en anglais par couple en français est un faux ami. Les mots sont des faux amis. Voilà.

Comment: @Lambie : D'accord :-)! J'ai compris ! On dit la même chose.

Comment: @Dimitris, tu as raison bien sûr. La phrase *la traduction est un faux ami* ne tient pas debout.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Personne en France de nos jours ne comprend le mot couple comme voulant dire quelques-uns.

En France de nos jours le mot couple (masc.) s'emploie pour parler de deux personnes vivant ensemble dans une relation amoureuse ou qui ont une activité ensemble.

Le mot couple a été aussi utilisé pour désigner deux personnes, comme dans ce vers de La Fontaine :

> Certain couple d'amis en un bourg établi,([*L'homme qui court après la fortune et l'homme qui l'attend*](https://www.bonjourpoesie.fr/lesgrandsclassiques/Poemes/jean_de_la_fontaine/lhomme_qui_court_apres_la_fortune_et_lhomme_qui_lattend))

dans lequel il est clair qu'il ne s'agit pas d'un couple engagé dans une relation sentimentale, mais juste de deux personnes. On peut parfois l'entendre employé pour parler de deux choses (par ex. un couple d'heures), cependant en France, ce sens est désormais classé comme vieilli ([Le Robert](https://dictionnaire.lerobert.com/definition/couple)).

Employé au féminin, dérivé de son sens qui désigne le lien avec lequel on attache deux chiens de chasse, couple pouvait désigner deux choses ou un petit nombre de choses. (Voir le TLF.) Mais il n'est plus du tout employé dans ce sens là en France. Par contre au Québec couple est encore employé pour dire « quelque, quelques-uns » ([Un couple n'est pas toujours deux](https://www.dufrancaisaufrancais.com/articles/une-couple-nest-pas-deux/)).

Dire si cet emploi Québécois est une survivance du français parlé par les premiers immigrants venus du Vieux Continent ou un calque de l'anglais me parait difficile, même si l'emprunt à l'anglais semble le plus vraisemblable à mes yeux.

Comment: J'ai déjà entendu la prononciation _coupelle_, ça pourrait être que le locuteur lui pensait que c'était un mot anglais et essayait de prononcer comme en anglais mais oui, possiblement...

Answer (score 3):

**I** C'est exact, « couple » n'est utilisé que pour des paires spéciales dans des contextes spéciaux. L'essentiel listé ci-dessous en ce qui concerne les personnes, les animaux et les choses,  provient du [TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/couple).

**PERSONNES**

1. **Ensemble de deux personnes liées par un sentiment, un intérêt quelconque**.
   ♦ Un couple de fripons (Ac.1835-1932).
   ♦ Vous me verrez tous les mercredis et les samedis. Nous causerons de nos affaires comme un couple d'amis (Balzac, Gobseck,1830, p. 404).
2. **Un homme et une femme réunis occasionnellement.**
   ♦  Un homme et une femme réunis occasionnellement.

**ANIMAUX**

1. **Réunis pour la procréation**.
   ♦ Rien ne sépare un couple d'isards, sinon la mort. Ils se choisissent, s'aiment, s'accouplent (Pesquidoux, Chez nous,1921, p. 35).
2. **Réunis pour un travail commun**.
   ♦  Un couple de bœufs au labour (Mauriac, Nœud vip.,1932, p. 264).

**CHOSES**

1. Littér. **Ensemble de deux choses abstraites, le plus souvent antithétiques**.
   ♦ Odyssée! Iliade! ô couple ardent et fort! Vaste dualité, fille d'un même effort! (Banville, Cariat.,La Voie lactée, 1842, p. 25).
   ♦ Le couple indissoluble, l'Être et le Néant (Sartre, Être et Néant,1943, p. 165).
2. **MAR. ,,Deux membres ou côtés d'un bâtiment qui s'élèvent d'un même point de la quille et sont opposés l'un à l'autre**`` (Ac.).
   ♦ Le maître couple. Les couples d'un vaisseau(Ac.).
3. **PHYS. ,,Deux forces égales, parallèles et de direction opposée, agissant en sens inverse aux extrémités d'un levier**`` (Ac. 1932).
   ♦  Moment d'un couple.

**II** Pourquoi cette différence entre l'anglais et le français ?  Tous les mots, après leur introduction dans une langue évoluent selon la culture du pays. « Couple » en anglais vient du vieux français, quand il voulait encore dire « a union of two, a pair ». Au cours des siècle chacun des deux a évolué différemment et il n'y a jamais eu personne d'un côté ou de l'autre qui se soit soucié des changements qui étaient faits dans l'autre à propos du mot « couple », et d'ailleurs, comment aurait-ce pu être autrement ?

**III** Pour une traduction  de l'anglais « couple » il peut s'agir de  « quelques », « des »  ou de « paire », « deux », ceci étant vrai parce que « couple » ne signifie plus seulement « deux » en anglais ; il s'est produit un glissement.

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/couple)

Ainsi, si vous voulez traduire  « She bought a couple of chicken. », il y a deux possibilités.

- Elle a acheté deux poulets.
- Elle a acheté des poulets.

La traduction dépend donc du contexte.

Answer (score 3):

Tout a déjà été dit à propos de la divergence du *couple* anglo-français... ;-)

Pour ce qui est d'une tournure idiomatique rendant l'expression en français, je propose:

> Il a fait **deux trois** fautes.